# My toString junit test is failing, I have an almost identical toString junit test that runs fine, I don't know what the problem is

Tags: java

The toString method:

```
@Test

    public void testToString() {

        Floor f = new Floor("Ground Floor");
        String toStr = f.toString();
        
        assertTrue("The toString method should be in standard convention format",
        toStr.startsWith("Room:[") && 
        toStr.contains("=" + f.getFloorName() + ", ") &&
        toStr.endsWith("=" + f.getRoomsTotal() + "]"));
    }
```

The get methods:

```
public String getFloorName() {
        return floorName;
    }

public int getRoomsTotal() {
        return rooms.size();
    }
```

I don't understand why it's failing, Floor holds an arraylist of Room which Room has an almost identical toString junit test:

```
@Test

    public void testToString() {
        Room room = new Room("Bathroom", 1);
        String toStr = room.toString();
        
        assertTrue("The toString method should be in standard convention format",
        toStr.startsWith("Room:[") && 
        toStr.contains("=" + room.getRoomName() + ", ") &&
        toStr.endsWith("=" + room.getOutletCount() + "]"));
    }
```

The constructors:

```
/** The default constructor */

public Floor() {
    floorName = "";
    rooms = new ArrayList<>();
}

/** The custom constructor, create a new instance with user given values.
 * 
 * @param floorName Set the floor name.
 */
public Floor(String floorName) {
    this.floorName = floorName;
    rooms = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The errors:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The toString method should be in standard convention format
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at lib.FloorTest.testToString(FloorTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:83)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

The override:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Floor:[floorName=" + floorName + ", rooms=" + rooms + "]";
    }
```

What's going wrong?

Updated this post with the constructors of floor and the errors printed out from the testing.

Comment: What about setting a break point and looking what toStr really looks like?

Comment: how do you override your .toString() method?

Comment: can't you see the test results printed out? Depending on your toString() implementation, if you haven't overriden it, your Floor toString() will start with ```Floor:[```

Comment: Rather than combining your checks into a single assertion, make each one separate and that will cue you into what is wrong with either your expectation or output.  We can't tell you much without the constructor(s), the toString() body, and the sample output.

Comment: I have added the constructors to the OP.

Comment: I have also added the override.

Comment: If I am correct, the toString() of Floor will have the prefix `Floor:[floorName=` and you are doing assert that it has prefix `Room:[`. Thus the assert will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You are overring the `toString()` method in the `Floor` class. The toString creates a string of format

```
"Floor:[floorName=" + floorName + ", rooms=" + rooms + "]";
```

Whereas in your assert statement you are checking that the prefix is `"Room:["`. That's why your unit test is failing. Also, you are asserting on the room count, but you haven't set the room count in the constructor.

Here’s what I would recommend for this situation, you can use different assert statement for each check, this will then point you to the check which is failing.

Comment: It was a very good read and indeed the points mentioned there are correct. Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `testToString` method that tests `toString` method of class `Floor`, the "test" instance of `Floor` contains no rooms. Hence, according to the code in your question, the `toString` method of class `Floor` returns the following:

```
Floor:[floorName=Ground Floor, rooms=[]]
```

Your `toString` method in class `Floor` does not return the number of rooms, so why do you test whether it ends with the number of rooms?

In order for your test code to work you need to either change the test code or change method `toString` in class `Floor`. For the latter, method `toString` in class `Floor` should be:

```java
return "Floor:[floorName=" + floorName + ", rooms=" + getRoomsTotal() + "]";
```

Then for the test instance of `Floor`, the `toString` method would return:

```
Floor:[floorName=Ground Floor, rooms=0]
```